# Table of Contents unbold chapter names

Tags: table-of-contents, chapters, bold

I require chapter names unbold in Table of Contents. Please guide me how I unbold the heading of chapter names only in Table of Contents.

Comment: Please provide us with a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv) so we can better help you. The ToC depends on the document class and perhaps other packages that you might be loading.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With the default [`report`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/unpacked/report.cls) and [`book`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/unpacked/book.cls) document classes, use [`etoolbox`](http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox) to patch `\l@chapter` and remove the use of `\bfseries`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{etoolbox}% http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\l@chapter}{\bfseries}{}{}{}% \patchcmd{<cmd>}{<search>}{<replace>}{<success>}{<failure>}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{A chapter}
\section{A section}
\end{document}
```

---

With [`tocloft`](http://ctan.org/pkg/tocloft) you need only redefine `\cftchapfont` and `\cftchappagefont` to some that doesn't include `\bfseries`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{tocloft}% http://ctan.org/pkg/tocloft
\renewcommand{\cftchapfont}{}
\renewcommand{\cftchappagefont}{}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{A chapter}
\section{A section}
\end{document}
```

---

[`memoir`](http://ctan.org/pkg/memoir) provides similar functionality to that of [`tocloft`](http://ctan.org/pkg/tocloft):

[image]

```
\documentclass{memoir}% http://ctan.org/pkg/memoir
\renewcommand{\cftchapterfont}{}
\renewcommand{\cftchapterpagefont}{}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{A chapter}
\section{A section}
\end{document}
```

---

Using [KOMA-script](http://ctan.org/pkg/koma-script), you can `\setkomafont` for `chapterentry` and `chapterentrypagenumber` accordingly:

[image]

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\setkomafont{chapterentry}{}
\setkomafont{chapterentrypagenumber}{}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{A chapter}
\section{A section}
\end{document}
```